# How to update/restore Windows 7 trusted root certificate store?

Tags: certificate, windows, updates

[Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/931125/how-to-get-a-root-certificate-update-for-windows) tells us, that there should be an update available.
When actually searching for it, only [two hits](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=root%20certificate%20update) show up and they are for windows 2000.
At the bottom of the article, they even promise a EasyFix (formerly FixIt), but the download button only leads to a [generic help page](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/help/2970908/how-to-use-microsoft-easy-fix-solutions), because the actual link the script points to doesn't exist. And neither of the "Fix"es is available anywhere else.

Very strange (or am I doing something utterly wrong? :-) )

Just for clarity: I am talking about Win7 and local operations, not CTL server or AD.

possibly related: [Reset Windows trusted certificates store to its default](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71313/reset-windows-trusted-certificates-store-to-its-default/160048#160048)